# Ionic fixed tabs menu doesn't work on tabbedSlideBox

Tags: css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I need to show different Ionic lists in a tabbed menu. The problem was include those tabs with the slide option. So i found this: [tabbedSlideBox](https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox).

Made it work, edited it's styling to go with my app. But I can't get the tabs menú to stay fixed and don't move.

I made a pen to show you my problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdjxrB

*Line 21* you can see the style inline with the `fixed` property that doesn't work. It keeps moving with the content, which is the opposite of what I need, I need to be able to move the list up and down and the tab menu should remain in it's place, but it should be able to move to right and left.

I believe it has something to do with the `translate3d`, but I can't figure out how to solve it without breaking the whole thing.

Tried to modify it's `directive` but I ended up breaking it..

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've been reading about fixed positioning and absolute3d transitions, and they don't get along, the fixed element behaves as it was absolute positioned because it takes it's container as reference for the positioning: http://codepen.io/markdebeer/pen/qrBDm, but if anyone comes with a solution to this i'll be grateful.

Comment: probably be a lot easer and a lot better to manage if you used tabs and states rather than tabs and a slide box. Also slide boxes are known for performance issues especially on android.

Comment: It's iOS only and I need that nice transition. But I think there's nothing to be done here except find another way to achieve this, i've been reading and fixed position don't get along with translate3d. The element takes it's parent div as the main container and behaves as an absolute positioned element..

Comment: You can do state animation transitions. You can even do a custom one and set different enter and exit animations for different states

Comment: Didn't want to reinvent the wheel, since I found this to be very good. I guess I have no other choice.

Comment: sorry wish i could be more help, i tried a lot of different approaches to navigation with tabs and navigating to states was the only one i found to work the way I thought it should.